# Double setting in odoo 13 User settings?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13, odoo-enterprise

strange case of Odoo 13 when we go to Settings -> Users and pick a user and open the form view.
then we get this:
[image]

double Accounting setting on the user, in the frist one we have Accountant and Advisor and in the second Account we have only the billing.
I checked the code and we dont have a custom module with messes with ir.module.category nor inherits the accounting for that matter.
The question is, have you ever had this case and how to combine these in one field setting?
In the base module i have found[image]

it takes the accounting field as different app, but we are using enterprise version, from invocing app comes the Billing and from accounting app from enterprise the other two. On a demo empty db these are in one field, on this db which has our data has these 2 options.
Any help is appreciated. Odoo 13 enterprise

Comment: Could be an odoo bug, have you tried the newest code for 13.0?

Comment: yes newest code updated from git

Comment: I don't see any problems at https://runbot.odoo.com in 13.0 Enterprise. So probably that is something you have to fix in your database. Have you tried to update module "base"? Keep in mind that it will lead to an update of probably all modules in your Odoo! That can lead to unexpected problems, for example errors from custom modules, overridden security rules (which were changed before), overridden email templates, lost translation, and so on.